# Possibly infected image

Tags: encryption, obfuscation, binwalk

Long story short I'v downloaded a template for my website and instead of images it has the .html files included, and at the beginning  those html files do include PNG IHDR , and they are being loaded perfectly by chrome, but something is telling me that there is some sort of script included.
Spent all night trying to figure this out, ran binwalk on it, without any clear hints, just producing a couple of zlib files
Any help would be appreciated

File in question - 
https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/www.giftsmenu.com/infected/Gomez.html

Comment: That’s a legitimate file type. What makes you think this is infected?

Comment: Simply because some images were included directly as .png and some as .html , even though the side does not really change, and let's just say it's quite popular in the community to steal traffic )